# c# interop excel range find first and last populated value

Tags: c#, excel, range, vsto, office-interop

I have a range (one row) and I want to know column position of first and last populated value in that range. This is how I am trying to calculate the position.

```
var xlRange = (Excel.Range)currentSheet.Cells[10, 1].EntireRow; // 10th row.
long firstColumn= (long)xlRange.get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlToRight).Column;
```

Sheet looks like this:

[image]

firstColumn returns 8. Which is correct. But I dont know how to get column position of last populated cell.

Also

```
long firstColumn= (long)xlRange.get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlToRight).Column;
```

return 12 for `firstColumn` when excel is setup as below:

[image]

I was expecting to get 1.

Any pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SpecialCells method available with Excel.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-specialcells-method-excel

In your case, you want to find the last cell so: *xlCellTypeLastCell
with no value i.e Type.Missing*.

```
Excel.Range lastCell = workSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing); 
Excel.Range myRange = workSheet.get_Range("B1", lastCell);
```

lastCell should give the its row and column values.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I can use xlCellTypeLastCell to find last cell. How do I get the position of first non empty element ?

Comment: Have you looked into UsedRange? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange.aspx